# Dask (delayed) vs pandas/function returns

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-delayed

I am trying to study a little bit about dask as a solution my parallel computing over some big data I have.

I have a code where I check a list of transactions and extract the number of active customers on every period (an active customer is a customer that has any transaction with last 90 days).

This is the code for sample data :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask 

num_variables = 10000
rng = np.random.default_rng()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' :  np.random.randint(1,999999999,num_variables),
    'date' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime(2021,6,1),datetime(2022,12,31))) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'product' : [np.random.choice(['giftcards', 'afiliates']) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'brand' : [np.random.choice(['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_4', 'brand_6']) for i in range(num_variables)],
    'gmv': rng.random(num_variables) * 100,
    'revenue': rng.random(num_variables) * 100})
```

**This is the "way 1" to execute (using pandas and simple functions)**

```
def active_clients(df : pd.DataFrame , date : date):
    date1 = (date - timedelta(days=90))
    date2 = date
    clients_base = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.date >= date1) & (df['date'].dt.date <= date2),'id'].nunique()
    return (date, clients_base)

months = []
results = []

dates = df.date.dt.to_period('M').drop_duplicates()
for i in dates:
    test = pd.Period(i,freq='M').end_time.date()
    months.append(test)

for i in months:
    test = active_clients(df,i)
    results.append(test)

results
```

The result here is a list of tuples:

```
[(datetime.date(2022, 7, 31), 24),
 (datetime.date(2022, 10, 31), 48),
 (datetime.date(2022, 12, 31), 43),
 (datetime.date(2022, 8, 31), 42),
 (datetime.date(2022, 9, 30), 46),
 (datetime.date(2022, 11, 30), 46),
 (datetime.date(2022, 6, 30), 11)]
```

**This is the "way 2" to execute (using dask delayed and functions)**

Now I am trying to do exactly the same by using dask delayed as a way to paralelize calculation.

```
@dask.delayed
def active_clients(df : pd.DataFrame , date : date):
    date1 = (date - timedelta(days=90))
    date2 = date
    clients_base = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.date >= date1) & (df['date'].dt.date <= date2),'id'].nunique()
    return (date, clients_base)

months = []
results = []

dates = df.date.dt.to_period('M').drop_duplicates()
for i in dates:
    test = dask.delayed(pd.Period(i,freq='M').end_time.date())
    months.append(test)

for i in months:
    test = dask.delayed(active_clients(df,i))
    results.append(test)

resultados = dask.compute(results)
```

resultados:

```
([(datetime.date(2022, 7, 31), 24),
  (datetime.date(2022, 10, 31), 48),
  (datetime.date(2022, 12, 31), 43),
  (datetime.date(2022, 8, 31), 42),
  (datetime.date(2022, 9, 30), 46),
  (datetime.date(2022, 11, 30), 46),
  (datetime.date(2022, 6, 30), 11)],)
```

The issues here are:

1. the code above returns me a tuple of a list of a tuple (different from the other code)
2. It does not seen to parallelize as only of one cores seems to be under hard work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix to your code is to remove nested `delayed` calls, as the relevant function is already decorated with `delayed` so there is no need to wrap it in another `delayed`:

```py
@dask.delayed
def active_clients(df : pd.DataFrame , date : date):
    date1 = (date - timedelta(days=90))
    date2 = date
    clients_base = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.date >= date1) & (df['date'].dt.date <= date2),'id'].nunique()
    return (date, clients_base)

months = []
results = []

dates = df.date.dt.to_period('M').drop_duplicates()
months = [pd.Period(i,freq='M').end_time.date() for i in dates]

for i in months:
    test = active_clients(df,i)  # note this will be delayed due to decoration of active_clients
    results.append(test)

resultados = dask.compute(*results)  # this will return a single list of results
```

The result of `dask.compute` will return a tuple as the code is intended to be used with multiple delayed values, so if you unpack the list of delayeds, then the computed results will be placed in `resultados` as a tuple.

Comment: Thanks. Some questions. What is the meaning of the "*" in this code dask.compute(*results) ?

Comment: Question 2. 
I am running the 2 versions of the code (your suggestion vs pandas original) on 100 thousands rows sample data.  Pandas version is always faster. Shouldn't dask use parallels process to speed up  ?

Comment: The asterisk in dask.compute is unpacking of an iterable, see https://realpython.com/lessons/unpacking-asterisk-operators/

Comment: Without the details of the data it's hard to know what's the bottleneck. One potential problem is that a large object is being passed around (`df`), so one option around that is to add: `df = dask.delayed(df)` before the loop.

Comment: I am using exactly the sample data written on original post. I've just changed it to a bigger sample (10m rows or bigger). I will try you suggestion. Thanks